# What do I need to do to this Meteor code to update content using autoform?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using accounts-ui for the login system.  I want to a create a profile form which I've got displaying using autoform.  When I try to submit the form the params are passed in the URL and the page refreshes but nothing is saved to the collection.

Any ideas?

Here's my schema (I've also tried just using a UserProfile schema but that didn't work)

```
    Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female']
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
    },
    pinCode: {
        type: Number,
        min: 7,
        max: 7
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        min: 9,
        max: 10
    }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: false
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

 Template.signupForm.helpers({
  users: function () {
  return Meteor.users;
 },
 userSchema: function () {
  return Schema.User;
 }
});

/* as an idea ....
Template.signupForm.editingDoc = function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: Meteor.userId()});
};
*/



//template
<template name="signupForm">
 <div class="panel-body">
   {{#autoForm schema=userSchema id="signupForm" doc=editingDoc  type="update"}}
 <fieldset>
   {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
 </fieldset>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
 {{/autoForm}}
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I added in collection=users and removed schema=userSchema.  The params are no longer passed in the URL and the page doesn't reload.  Nothing is entered into the user profile though.  Also changed the type="insert" but that has had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really late but if anyone need this, the issue you where having is you never gave it the user collection:

```
{{#autoForm 
  collection='Meteor.users'  //this was your issue
  id="signupForm" 
  doc=editingDoc  
  type="update"
}}
```

If you wanted to you could even limit the form to just the profile with:

```
{{#autoForm 
   collection='Meteor.users' 
   schema="Schema.UserProfile" //both collection & schema will render schema
   id="signupForm" 
   doc=editingDoc  
   type="update"
}}
```